# Optionally present images as thumbnails

Tags: discussion, feature-request, images

This question relates to [this Meta Stack Overflow question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74312/191347).

Could we provide a method (possibly optional) that shows embedded images first as a thumbnail or medium-sized image preview and then show the full image when clicked (in a lightbox or similar UI)?

[A recent answer of mine](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/23645/11687) demanded the inclusion of a large number of images, many of which are very large. I feel like my answer (once it had been relatively highly-rated) consumes the whole discussion and acts as a disincentive for anyone else with useful input to provide answers of their own (since they'll start buried under my very long answer).

I would follow the instructions on the afore-mentioned Meta SO answer to manually implement this, but the overhead of doing that for every image in every such answer is very high and the UX of reading the answer would be relatively terrible too (having to either make liberal use of the back button or opening all my examples in separate tabs and keep switching between them to see the image and my comments about it).

**Edit:** One other factor that I didnt mention here; since the images are automatically scaled to the width of the container, wide or high-resolution images (like the NeXTSTEP screenshot in my example) are effectively useless on the mobile site without some way to see the image at its full size.

Comment: Does the [Thumbnail uploader script](http://stackapps.com/q/3507) mentioned in the Meta SO answers not help then? (I haven't used it; perhaps it needs improving)

Comment: @AndrewLeach I haven't used it (I don't use either of the supported browsers to browse UX.SE), but personally I'd like to see it folded into the standard image insertion control so authors wouldn't need to install a script to use it. As stated in my edit, it would be really helpful for the mobile version of the site to see this sort of thing more widely adopted for screenshots posted on the site, so making it available (and thus discoverable) to authors still seems like a worthwhile feature to me.